# How to interpret this visualisation?

Tags: data-visualization, interpretation

I am trying to figure out if this is a good plot or an example of bad plot.
https://www.tcsnycmarathon.org/analytics

I am trying to figure out what does %Finish by Gender plot on the right is conveying? For any bar (i.e. for any one year), I can think of only two things

1. In the year 2015, Out of total finishers, 40 % were women. But this cannot be right because the bar length is not at 100 %
2. In the year 2015, 65% of the participant finished the race. This can be right but if that is the case, I do not understand blue and pink portions. It cannot be that 40% % of that 65 % were women.

I would really some thoughts on if this is just a bad choice plot or there is a better interpretation which I am missing.

[image]

Comment: Maybe it says that in 2015 only 60% of entrants finished the race, and about 2/3 of the finishers were women.

Comment: The bars are overlaid rather than stacked.  The total heights of the blue and pink bars remain constant at 100%.

Comment: @whuber No only 1970 bar is at 100%. Rest are much smaller than that.

Comment: @BruceET I thought so too but in that case one needs to ignore the scale when reading pink bar because that 40% is relative to max. Also, if it means only 1/3 of finishers were men, I find it hard to believe.

Comment: PagMax, that's not what I'm saying.  At the right, *all* bars begin at zero--you just cannot see that because the pink bars overlap the blue bars.  The *sums* of their heights are always 100%.  That fact is blatantly obvious when you place a horizontal mirror at a height of 50%: it shows how decreases in the blue height are invariably balanced by increases in the pink height.

Comment: Ahh  that makes much more sense. Thanks @whuber